# iText doesn't like my special characters

Tags: java, pdf, utf-8, itext, diacritics

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using iText.
The file gets produced just fine, but I can seem to use special characters like german ä, ö, ...
The sentence I want to be written is (for example)

> ■ ...ä...ö...

but the output is

> â– ...Ã¤...Ã¶...

(I had to kind of blur the sentences, but I guess you see what I'm talking about...)

Somehow this black block-thing and all "Umlaute" can't be generated ...
The font used is the following:

```
private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
  Font.BOLD);
```

So there should be no problem about the font not having these characters...
I'm using IntelliJ Idea to develop, the encoding of the .java file is set to UTF-8, so there should be no problem too...

I'm kind of lost here; does anyone know what i may do to get it working?

Thanks in advance and greetz
gilaras

**---------------UPDATE---------------**

So here's (part of) the code:

```
@Controller
public class Generator {
  ...
  Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 9f, Font.BOLD);
  ...

  Paragraph intro = new Paragraph("Ich interessiere mich für ...!", font_12_bold);

  Paragraph wantContact = new Paragraph("■ Ich hätte gerne ... ", font); 

  ...

  Phrase south = new Phrase("■ Süden    □ Ost-West  ...");

  ...


  @RequestMapping(value = "/generatePdf", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String generatePdf(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException, DocumentException, com.lowagie.text.DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
    addMetaData(document);
    document.open();
    addContent(document, request);
    document.add(new Paragraph("äöü"));
    document.close();
    return "";
  }

  private void addContent(Document document, HttpServletRequest request)
      throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    preface.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Rückantwort", catFont));
    addEmptyLine(preface, 2);
    preface.add(intro);
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);

    if (request.getParameter("dec1").equals("wantContact")) {
      preface.add(wantContact);
    } else {
      ...
    }
    document.add(preface);
  }

  private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
  }

  private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
    document.addTitle("...");
    document.addSubject("...");
    document.addKeywords("...");
    document.addAuthor("...");
    document.addCreator("...");
  }

}
```

I had to take some things out, but I kept some Umlaut-character and other special characters, so that you can see, where the problem occurs ... :-)

Comment: I skipped the part with HttpServletRequest... and I get all displayed correctly except the '■' bullet

Comment: That's kind of strange ... oO Because it doesn't really have anything to do with hardcoded strings, does it? At least it shouldn't ... Anyways, didn't change anything here >.< I guess the best thing to do is to look in another direction and maybe the result does not have to a pdf...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try and embed the font using this technique:

```
BaseFont times = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(times, 12, Font.BOLD);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it didn't change anything :-/

Comment: There might be other code needed to embed the font. One version to embed all Fonts:
FontFactory.defaultEmbedding = true;

Also, does Times New Roman usually supports these characters :) ?

Comment: FontFactory.defaultEmbedding = true; didn't solve it either :-/ Times New Roman should have these chars, ... I'm not sure, though, and I don't really know how to find out ... ?! If everyday work with Word and stuff is usual, than it Times New Roman supports these chars ... :-/

Comment: I just tried itextpdf 5.1.3 (I am on Ubuntu, not Windows) with this code: // Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
  document.open();
  Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);
  Paragraph pg = new Paragraph();
  pg.setFont(font);
  pg.add("Test ■ ...ä...ö... Test");
  document.add(pg);
  document.close(); //

and I get the two umlaut characters correct. The black block is not rendered but it might be not part of Times font

Comment: I tried your code too; it worked. Now I'm totally confused; my code does - of course - nothing else ... and doesn't work though ... tried to change the font again to the one you used in your example; no success :-/ I just don't get what may be wrong, because everything is - expect for the words I add - the same ...

Comment: Can you post your code that doesn't work (if there is nothing confidential)?